# Using cheerio in reactjs to replace text before rendering it to webpage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cheerio

I am using `reverseproxy` to take some blog pages from my `django` backend and style them according to Header/Footer etc of the react frontend.

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

module.exports = function (app) {
  // Proxy requests to URLs that start with /blog/ to the backend server
  app.use(
    '/blog',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'http://localhost:8000/blog',
      changeOrigin: true,
      pathRewrite: {
        '^/blog': '',
      },
      onProxyRes: async (proxyRes, req, res) => {
        let data = [];

        proxyRes.on('data', (chunk) => {
          data.push(chunk);
        });

        proxyRes.on('end', async () => {
          let responseBody = Buffer.concat(data).toString();


          const contentType = proxyRes.headers['content-type'];
          console.log('Content-Type:', contentType);


          if (contentType && contentType.includes('text/html')) {
            const $ = cheerio.load(responseBody);


            const newSection = `
              <div>
                This is a test
              </div>
            `;


            $('body').prepend(newSection);


            console.log('New Section Content:', newSection);

            responseBody = $.html();
            console.log('New HTML Content:', responseBody);
          }


          res.end(responseBody);
        });
      },
    })
  );
};
```

I can see the console.log statements showing the correct `html`, however the browser doesn't have the correct `html`, it comes through with no changes.

Original html:

```
    
        Test Template 
    
    
        Blog test post
```

This is same as what I see after reverseproxy.